# postgresql - Appending data from JSON file to a table

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am using two columns from the iris dataset as an example - sepal_length and sepal_width.

I have two tables

`create table iris(sepal_length real, sepal_width real);`, and

`create table raw_json(data jsonb);`

And inside the JSON file I have data like this

`[{"sepal_width":3.5,"sepal_length":5.1},{"sepal_width":3.0,"sepal_length":4.9}]`

First thing I do is `copy raw_json from '/data.json';`

So far I have only been able to figure out how to use `jsonb_array_elements`.

`select jsonb_array_elements(data) from raw_json;` gives back

```
           jsonb_array_elements            
-------------------------------------------
 {"sepal_width": 3.5, "sepal_length": 5.1}
 {"sepal_width": 3.0, "sepal_length": 4.9}
```

I want to insert (append actually) the data from `raw_json` table into `iris` table. I have figured out that I need to use either `jsonb_to_recordset` or `json_populate_recordset`. But how?

Also, could this be done without the `raw_json` table?

PS - Almost all the existing SE questions use a raw json string inside their queries. So that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must extract the jsons from the output of `jsonb_array_elements` used in `from` clause

```
INSERT INTO iris(sepal_length,sepal_width)
select (j->>'sepal_length' ) ::real,
       (j->>'sepal_width'  ) ::real
from raw_json cross join jsonb_array_elements(data) as j;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=318010348150c90ce615bdb9d1037259)

Comment: thanks! I was able to solve this issue by doing `json_populate_recordset(null::iris, data)`. I have one more issue though. I am doing `copy raw_json from '/data.json';` to load the JSON data from the file. And it inserts all the records into a single cell. What if there is a list of million records inside the file? Would my approach still be efficient?

Comment: @JeetParekh : You're welcome. This answers your original question. If you think it helped you, consider accepting it. If you have further queries that are not fully related to this question, you should ask them as a separate question in StackOverflow.