# postgresql - How to insert a large list of JSON objects from a file?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

This is a follow up to this question - [postgresql - Appending data from JSON file to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55527677/4779852).

I have a list of records as JSON objects inside a file like this

`[{"sepal_width":3.5,"sepal_length":5.1},{"sepal_width":3.0,"sepal_length":4.9}, ...]`

There might be millions of records inside the list.

Right now I am using `copy raw_json from './data.json';` to get the data into postgresql. But it is inserting the entire file contents into a single cell. Is the previous approach still efficient for millions of records?

Is it possible to send the contents of `copy from './data.json';` into `jsonb_array_elements` before passing it to the `raw_json` table?

Right now I have thought of using

```
\set content `cat ./data.json`
```

What's an efficient way of handling such large JSON files?

Comment: The hard limit on single attribute in PostgreSQL is 1 GB. So if your JSON file is below that, you are safe. Do you encounter any problems with `raw_json` method? Of course it's expected to have pretty high memory usage while parsing the JSON.

Comment: yes, I faced an issue when I was importing data from a file with 180k records.